# Are GetById, GetByX CRUD or Business logic methods or both of them

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, repository-design

Colleague of mine told me - we don't have a Business logic, we only have CRUD like GetById, GetBySearchTerm, GetByParentID....so I started to wondering about these words.

After reading about DDD, those methods are CRUD, they have a mechanism to fetch data (also store, update, delete...) based on some specific code (usually SQL).

If Business analyst say me: "We need to show data about specific customer". 
In my opinion this IS (GetById) a Business process, GetById should be placed inside Business logic part of the application and it contacts repository to fetch a data. Repository with CRUD methods is responsible to persist data based on some criteria.

I Know this question can lead to debate to have repository with atomic methods (GetById, GetBySearchTerm, GetByParentiId...) but my question is only simple - are those methods are CRUD or Business logic methods.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should not be querying your domain model for any reason other than domain operations that are part of the *write* / *transactional* side of things.  This side of things is more interested in commands issued at your domain in order to *do* / *perform* operations.

Anything related to displaying *data* should come from as simple a *query* / *read model* as is possible.

If you find that your *queries* require domain interaction you probably have a scenario where you may need to tell your domain to do something and, once completed, you can request the data through the query side.

Comment: When app query a data it is also transactional process. I think, I didn't undserstand you. Can you elaborate, or simplify you answer.

Comment: Typically when you query data it isn't transactional.  There wouldn't be too much sense in using a transaction for selects.  In any event, I mean transactional in the sense of the command / write side of things (OLTP) as opposed to reading data (much more closely related to OLAP).

Answer (score 0):

Not every application is a DDD application. Some applications are just simple CRUD

The business logic would be the part of the application where you validate inputs (like get by id and id is a number between 1 and 99999). This then is passed on to the repository for the actual query.

But if your application is really a crud application then trying to apply DDD isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Those methods can't be the business methods at all. As a CQRS practitioner i would suggest you to have different models for command and query side. May be you create a different bounded context that serves the whole reading (Query) process (You can create anemic /DTOs here) and another domain model that serves pure business logic purpose.

You can take a look at my blog for command and query separation.

https://aspxsushil.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/command-and-query-object-pattern/